# How to prevent the canvas from blocking my clicks?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my unity scene, I have two different Canvas, one is set on "Screen Space - Overlay", and the other is set on "World Space". I tried using IsPointerOverGameObject to prevent the clicks on the second canvas to go through, but the first one seems to block everything.

[Here's my scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v886.png)

I circled in blue the "World Space" canvas and in red the "Screen Space - Overlay" one. I need to have the blue one stop clicks from going through, but allow the red one to be clicked through.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just disable the `Graphic Raycaster` Component and will fix:

[image]

Comment: And if this doesn't work, or if you still want the raycaster, then check the order in scene

Answer (score 0):

if you have an image component disable raycast target
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t3VS.png)

Comment: This is better suited as a comment.

Comment: I digress, @MrDiamond. This is an _attempt at an answer_, see [Does a "wild guess" qualify as an answer or should it be a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412098/does-an-admittedly-wild-guess-qualify-as-an-answer-or-should-it-be-a-comment)